# Hurst Exponent turns nan - Python 3

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance

I'm wanting to determine whether a time series is mean-reverting or not, but I'm running into some issues when calculating the Hurst exponent. It's supposed to print 0.5-ish, but instead I get a "nan". All help would be appreciated.

I get the following error/warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)
```

Below is the code I'm working on.

```
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
from datetime import datetime

from pandas_datareader import DataReader
security = DataReader("GOOG", "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2013,1,1))
ts.adfuller(security['Adj Close'], 1)



from numpy import cumsum, log, polyfit, sqrt, std, subtract
from numpy.random import randn

def hurst(ts):
    """Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts"""

    lags = range(2, 100)

    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)


    return poly[0]*2.0


gbm = log(cumsum(randn(100000))+1000)
mr = log(randn(100000)+1000)
tr = log(cumsum(randn(100000)+1)+1000)

print ("Hurst(GBM):   %s" % hurst(gbm))
print ("Hurst(MR):    %s" % hurst(mr))
print ("Hurst(TR):    %s" % hurst(tr))
print ("Hurst(SECURITY):  %s" % hurst(security['Adj Close']))



print ("Hurst(GBM):   %s" % hurst(gbm))
print ("Hurst(MR):    %s" % hurst(mr))
print ("Hurst(TR):    %s" % hurst(tr))
print ("Hurst(SECURITY):  %s" % hurst(security['Adj Close']))
Hurst(GBM):   0.5039604262314196
Hurst(MR):    -2.3832407841923795e-05
Hurst(TR):    0.962521148986032
Hurst(SECURITY):  nan
__main__:11: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

Comment: One or more of the values in `ts` are zero. The warning and result you see is NumPy attempting to take the natural logarithm of zero, and setting the result to Not a Number, `nan`.

Comment: Alternatively, since you're doing `std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))`, that result may be zero instead of `ts` (more likely even than a value in `ts` being zero), and thus one or more values in `tau` are zero, with the same warning and final `nan` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when sending Series as the ts argument.
All you have to do is send a List not a Series or:

```
def hurst(ts):
    """Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts"""
    ts = ts if not isinstance(ts, pd.Series) else ts.to_list()
    lags = range(2, 100)
    tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]
    poly = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)
    return poly[0]*2.0
```

NaN values might be an issue as well, I would check if is ok to dropna() before to_list()

Comment: Thank you for the input!

I found a way around it.
When I isolated the closing prices or made a excel file with a single column, I could run the data through the function with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that the `Series[<slice>]` syntax returns the corresponding index for each slice, and the `-` operator works on per-index equality (not actual location).

Example:

```
s = pd.Series(range(5))
s[2:] - s[:-2]
=>
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Clearly, that's not what we expected. To see why we can use concat to create a row-by-row dataframe of `s[2:], s[:-2]`, respectively.

```
pd.concat([s[2:], s[:-2]], axis=1)
=>
    0   1
0   NaN 0.0
1   NaN 1.0
2   2.0 2.0
3   3.0 NaN
4   4.0 NaN
```

Given this input the result of the `tau =`  equation in the hurst function is a list of (mostly) nan values.

The solution to work with Series natively is to use `Series.shift()` instead of array slicing:

```
def hurst(ts):
  ... 

  # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
  tau = [sqrt((ts - ts.shift(-lag)).std()) for lag in lags]

  ...
```

Alternatively, pass the `Series.values` to the original function, which passes a numpy array.